# SQL loop with data aggregation

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySql 5.5.38 and got a following table (this is just a snippet, real one contains ~500 products):

```
+------+-------+----------+-------+--------+
| id   | date  | product  | type  | sales  |
+------+-------+----------+-------+--------+
| 4513 | 14958 | XXXXXXX  |     1 |      3 |
| 4514 | 14958 | XXXXXXX  |     2 |      5 |
| 4519 | 14958 | YYYYYYY  |     1 |     10 |
| 4531 | 14958 | YYYYYYY  |     3 |    150 |
| 4534 | 14959 | ZZZZZZZ  |     1 |      5 |
| 4536 | 14959 | ZZZZZZZ  |     2 |      5 |
|+------+-------+----------+-------+--------+
```

from which I need to generate daily sales volume by product:

```
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| date  | XXXXXXX  | YYYYYYY  | ZZZZZZZ  |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 14958 |        8 |      110 |        0 |
+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| 14959 |        0 |        0 |       10 |
|+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The result table has to look exactly like above - with products in columns and days in row.

Just looking for some pointers, not a working solution. Thanks, Pawel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/1169798

Comment: you can do it in one query, use cases for your xxxx,yyyy,xxx and just sum, and group by.

Comment: you want to do sum(sales) and group by the product and order by the date

Comment: Might this be a pivot table?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic aggregation, use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) with [CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN product= "', 
    product, '" THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS '
    , product))
INTO @sql
FROM
  my_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM my_table 
                   GROUP BY date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Use conditional `case` with `group by` (for static)

```
SELECT  s.date,

SUM(
CASE 
WHEN s.product='XXXXXXX' 
THEN s.sales
ELSE 0 
END
) AS 'XXXXXXX',

SUM(
CASE 
WHEN s.product='YYYYYYY' 
THEN s.sales
ELSE 0 
END
) AS 'YYYYYYY',

SUM(
CASE 
WHEN s.product='ZZZZZZZ' 
THEN s.sales
ELSE 0 
END
) AS 'ZZZZZZZ'

FROM my_table s
GROUP BY s.date;
```

Comment: @pawel: Was this helpful ?

Comment: The data I provided is obviously a snippet of the table. The acutal one contains a couple of hundreds of products. So, hardcoded cases won't get me as far as I hoped.

Comment: @PawelPogorzelski: I guess now it should help.

Comment: @Rokcse thanks, coudn't get GROUP_CONCAT working so I actually wrote a Java snippet that genrated conditional case queries you suggested. +1