# Convert Row data to column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL table which stores data in this format

```
Type|Month|Count
----+-----+-------
1   |9    |4
3   |9    |7
99  |9    |2
1   |10   |6
3   |10   |7
99  |10   |9
.......
```

Type column can hold either of 3 values 1,3,99.
Month will hold values from 1 to 12.
Count can be anything random.

The output I desire is something like this:

```
Month|Type1|Type3|Type99
-----+-----+-----+-------
9    |4    |7    |2
10   |6    |7    |9
................
```

I came across [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0467e/14) Demo but couldn't understand much from it.

Here's a sample [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ba8c2/1) with demo data.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At least create a fiddle with your sample data.

Comment: added link to fiddle with sample data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below query, what you need is know as MYSQL pivot and below query solves your issue

**STATIC WAY**

```
SELECT Month, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN 'count' ELSE 0 END) AS Type1,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 3 THEN 'count' ELSE 0 END) AS Type3,  
 SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 99 THEN 'count' ELSE 0 END) AS Type99
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Month
```

**DYNAMIC WAY**

use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) with [CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN Type= ', 
    Type, ' THEN count ELSE 0 END) AS '
    , 'Type', Type))
INTO @sql
FROM
  my_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Month, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM my_table 
                   GROUP BY Month');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: @Nilesh Barai, was this helpful ?

Comment: Its not working. It shows values 0 for type3 and type99 columns

Comment: this is what i need. Simple and elegant!!

Comment: @Mihai: You are not the only one who know mysql, please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263917/sql-loop-with-data-aggregation/26264344#26264344

Comment: @Mihai: I did my copy paste from my own concept, refer that link.