# How do I display data into two column with Thymeleaf and HTML?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

I have been searching left and right but still can't find a good solution to this. Also I'm pretty new to programing so please excuse the way I describe thing :). I'm using Spring, MySQL, Java, Thymeleaf.

Basically, I have a list of object passed from the controller:

[person [code=1, name=A, car=ford1],person [id=2, name=A, car=ford2], person [id=1, name=B, car=toyota1], person [id=2, name=B, car=toyota2] ]

I want to display this data using Thymeleaf in either an HTML table or bootstrap grid system.

This is what I got:

```
<div>
    <table
      class="
        table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive-xl
      "
    >
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Car</th>
           <th>Name</th>
          <th>Car</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="person :${listOfPerson}">
          <td>
            [[${person.id}]]
          </td>
          <td>
            [[${person.name}]]
          </td>
          <td>
            [[${person.car}]]
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

so this display the data like this:

| ID | Name | Car | Name | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ford1 |  |  |
| 2 | A | ford2 |  |  |
| 1 | B | toyota1 |  |  |
| 2 | B | toyota2 |  |  |

but I want it to display like this:

| ID | Name | Car | Name | Car |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | ford1 | B | toyota1 |
| 2 | A | ford2 | B | toyota2 |

I think I probably need to somehow split this data into id 1 and id 2. Here is two ways I could think of doing this:

- Using Thymeleaf th:if="${person.id.equals(1)} to get the data for id 1 and then repeat for 2, I just don't know how to put this into the table.
- format the data using a query, I'm not sure how to do this without turning the result into one single column with GROUP_CONCAT.

Maybe I need to change the SQL table, please give me some suggestion.

Edit: So I think I found the answer to this [MySQL pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329159/convert-row-data-to-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your list of persons by id. Let's say you have a list like this:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new Person(1, "A", "ford1"),
    new Person(2, "A", "ford2"),
    new Person(1, "B", "toyota1"),
    new Person(2, "B", "toyota2")
)
```

Group it:

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> groupedByIdPersons = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId));
```

Use it in Thymeleaf:

1. Iterate over whole map in `th:block` to create header. Repeats as many times as there are collections grouped by the id.
2. Iterate over whole map to extract both key/value, then iterate only over values in `th:block`

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th:block th:each="elem : ${groupedByIdPersons}">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Car</th>
        </th:block>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="elem : ${groupedByIdPersons}">
        <th:block th:each="person : ${elem.value}">
            <td>${person.id}</td>
            <td>${person.name}</td>
            <td>${person.car}</td>
        </th:block>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```